# Java timezone conversion

Tags: java, timezone

I have a String, representing time in UTC.
I need to convert it to long representing milliseconds since midnight at EST, considering daylight saving times.
For example, in January, the offset is 5 hours, but in June 4 hours.

However, the code below displays the same offset of 5 hours for both June and January.
The variable `tzOffset = -18000000` (=-5 hours), regardless the date month.

Please advise,

Thanks!

```
package TimeConversion;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.*;

public class TimeConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String utcTime = "20100101120000000";
        SimpleDateFormat sdfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
        sdfIn.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));        
        long utcMillis = sdfIn.parse(utcTime).getTime();
        long tzOffset = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST").getOffset(utcMillis);
        long estMillis = utcMillis + tzOffset;
        long estMillisSinceMidnight = estMillis % 86400000;
        System.out.println("utcTime = " + utcTime + "\nestMillisSinceMidnight = " + estMillisSinceMidnight + "(" + 24.0 * estMillisSinceMidnight / 86.4e6 + ")");
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is in the TimeZone.getOffset method, which calls TimeZone.inDaylightTime(). inDaylightTime() always returns false.   Here is the bug description:         http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do;jsessionid=1d2668d1800d34ffffffffad585cf97e632b8?bug_id=6609359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could steal some code from [this calendar conversion utility](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/util/DateTimeUtils.java). What you probably need is getLocalTime. Disclaimer: I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Duration                                                     // Represent a span-of-time not attached to the timeline, on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds.
.between(                                                    // Instantiate a `Duration` by calculating time elapsed between a pair of moments.
    LocalDateTime.parse(                                     // Represent a date with time-of-day but lacking the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.
        "20100101120000000" ,                                // Tip: Use standard ISO 8601 formats instead of inventing your own.
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmssSSS" ) 
    )                                                        // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
    .atZone(                                                 // Place this date-with-time in the context of a particular time zone to determine a moment, a specific point on the timeline.
        ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )                      // Never use 2-4 character pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `EDT`. Real time zone names are in `Continent/Region` format.
    )                                                        // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .toLocalDate()                                           // Extracts the date-only portion from a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .atStartOfDay(                                           // Determine the first moment of the day on that date as seen in a particular time zone.
        ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
    )                                                        // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object, rather than altering original. (immutable objects)                     
    ,
    LocalDateTime.parse( 
        "20100101120000000" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmssSSS" ) 
    )
    .atZone(
        ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
    )
)                                                             // Returns a `Duration`.
.toMillis()                                                   // Returs a `long` integer.
```

Beware of possible data loss as any microseconds or nanoseconds are not accounted for with a coarser count of milliseconds.

## ISO 8601

> String utcTime = "20100101120000000";

By the way, rather than invent your own formats, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for exchanging date-time values as text. The standard was invented for that very purpose.

## *java.time*

Define a formatting pattern to match your input.

```
String input = "20100101120000000";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmssSSS" ) ;
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` object, because your input lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

If you know for certain the intended time zone for that date and time-of-day, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

I am guessing by `EDT` you mean east coast time somewhere North America or the Caribbean. That could be any number of various time zones such as `America/New_York`, `America/Louisville`, and so on. I arbitrarily guessed `America/Montreal` for my code example here.

Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EDT` or `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!). Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

You want to get elapsed time since the first moment of the day as seen in that time zone, until this `ZonedDateTime` object we just determined.

Let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day. In some zones on some dates, the day may not start at 00:00.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfDay = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed time as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html). Feed inputs as [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) objects, which represent the same moment as our [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) objects but are adjusted to UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

```
Duration d = Duration.between(
    zdtStartOfDay.toInstant() ,
    zdt.toInstant() 
);
```

Apparently you want to represent that span-of-time as a count of milliseconds. Beware of possible data-loss, as the `ZonedDateTime` & `Instant` classes resolve to the finer nanoseconds.

```
long millis = d.toMillis() ;  // Report entire span-of-time as a count of milliseconds. Beware: possible data loss as any microseconds and nanoseconds are ignored.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DySaeU). We get a result of 12 hours.

> d.toString(): PT12H
>
> millis: 43200000